# Plotting error with pandas and matplot in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I keep getting this error in my code. I see that it is with line 6 but I do not understand the error. I grabbed the code straight from the examples page of the Alpha vantage api documentation. I changed the AUTH KEY for obvious reasons. [image: Python error screen and code]

Answer (score 0):

there's no column names 'close'
the best practice is to use a ide. like jupyter, spider, or pycharm where you can see your variables.
in this. first `print(data.columns)`. then choose a column which you want. and make sure for spaces. may be `close` is `close`  or something else.

Comment: Thank you, I just realized that it is looking for "4. close"

Comment: Upvote the answer it solves question. it will help me